# rendering button in map function in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, map-function

I am trying to map through an array of items and putting a button with name of that item while mapping. But button is not rendering. Why?

```
return (
        <div>
            {/*<button value={categories[0]} onClick={e => categoryChangedHandler(e)} style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>{categories[0]}</button>*/}
            {categories.map((category, index) => {
                console.log("catogoried.map called and categories= " + category);
                <button value={category} onClick={e => categoryChangedHandler(e)} style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>{category}</button>
            })
            }
```

The button in comments is working but not in map function. Why?

Comment: return statement is missing (return <button ...)